# Open my form results in Iframe on another page

Tags: html, forms, iframe

Hi I have page "A" with small form search for Domains and page "B" with my site design and layouts and one "ifarme" named "domains"

now what I need is when the users search for domains they will see the results in page "B" in the "ifarme" named "domains"

this is the code for page "A"

```
    <form action="http://www.iwebtool.com/tool/tools/domain_availability/domain_availability.php" method="get" name="pageform" onsubmit="return validate(this);" target="http://hostnile.com/includes/pages/foo.php">

<input type="text" name="domain" size="30" /> 

<select name="ext">
<option>.com</option>
<option>.net</option>
<option>.org</option>
<option>.biz</option>
<option>.ca</option>
<option>.cc</option>
<option>.co</option>
<option>.info</option>
<option>.me</option>
<option>.mobi</option>
<option>.us</option>
<option>.ws</option>
<option>.asia</option>
<option>.tv</option>
</select>

                    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="5">

                    <input type="submit" value="Check" />
                    </form>
                    </div>

    <script language="JavaScript">
    function validate(theform) {
    if (theform.domain.value == "") { alert("No domain entered"); return false; }
    return true;
    }
    </script>
```

and page "B"

just has the layout and my "iframe" named domains.

**Edit**

```
<form action="http://hostnile.com/includes/pages/foo.php" method="get" name="pageform" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
```

and the "pageB" with iframe

```
<iframe src="http://www.iwebtool.com/tool/tools/domain_availability/domain_availability.php?<?php echo 'http://'.$_REQUEST['domain'].$_REQUEST['ext']?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Just to confirm - when user submits a form you need to display resulting page in the iframe?

Comment: Hi Yuriy, yes but the results is coming from iwebtool.com site and the ifarme is in another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the code below is what you are looking for your foo.php.
It gets the **domain** and **ext** parameter from the url and build an url to show in the src of the iframe.

One point you got remember is that certain website block the option to be opened inside an iframe, for ie: google.com

```
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="<?php echo 'http://'.$_REQUEST['domain'].$_REQUEST['ext']?>"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi fmodos, I tried this but still when I click submit it go to the iwebtool.com site without even look to my foo page.

Comment: you need to change the action property of the form to point to your foo.php... just do action="foo.php", if it is in the same folder of the page "A", also remove the target property of the form

Comment: I just made the changes and now it go to foo.php but the domain is empty and so the ext so the results is empty too what I did wrong here

Comment: please paste in a http://jsfiddle.net/ the source code of the page when the browser loaded the foo.php

Comment: and this is the URL of the Iframe when it comes empty "http://www.iwebtool.com/tool/tools/domain_availability/domain_availability.php?http://"

Comment: I didnt see the iframe code there.. are you sure that you added my iframe example to this page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30025/discussion-between-fmodos-and-yousef-altaf)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `target` attribute of the form. Instead of URL that you currently have use Iframe name, e.g.

```
<form action="http://www.iwebtool.com/tool/tools/domain_availability/domain_availability.php" name="pageform" onsubmit="return validate(this);" target="my_iframeB">
```

And if you have your current iframe as

```
<iframe name="my_iframeB" src="http://hostnile.com/includes/pages/foo.php" />
```

Current source of the Iframe in question will be replaced by the one from iwebtool.com

Comment: thanks for help but how the form will go to "page B" we didn't even mention it's name I just said the target "my_iframeB" but "my_iframeB" is on another page not on the same page

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the requirement a bit. In that case your form on "Page A" needs to post with Action to "Page B". "Page B" in turn collects all the parameters, combines them with URL (iwebtool.com) and assigns the result to the SRC of the iframe. This can even be done in client-side JavaScript